# EKS: Unhealthy nodes in the kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I’m getting an error when using terraform to provision node group on AWS EKS.
Error: error waiting for EKS Node Group (xxx) creation: `NodeCreationFailure: Unhealthy nodes in the kubernetes cluster.`

And I went to console and inspected the node. There is a message `“runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized”`.

I have 5 private subnets and connect to Internet via NAT.

Is someone able to give me some hint on how to debug this?

Here are some details on my env.

```
Kubernetes version: 1.18
Platform version: eks.3
AMI type: AL2_x86_64
AMI release version: 1.18.9-20201211
Instance types: m5.xlarge
```

There are three workloads set up in the cluster.

```
coredns, STATUS (2 Desired, 0 Available, 0 Ready)
aws-node STATUS (5 Desired, 5 Scheduled, 0 Available, 0 Ready) 
kube-proxy STATUS (5 Desired, 5 Scheduled, 5 Available, 5 Ready)
```

go inside the `coredns`, both pods are in pending state, and conditions has `“Available=False, Deployment does not have minimum availability”` and `“Progress=False, ReplicaSet xxx has timed out progressing”`
go inside the one of the pod in `aws-node`, the status shows `“Waiting - CrashLoopBackOff”`

Comment: Which pod network add-on are you using? Was it installed correctly?

Comment: I'm using the default AWS network, which is Amazon VPC CNI.

Comment: please take a look on this issues [network is not ready: [runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/issues/284).

Comment: yes, it was the permission boundary that I set for the eks role. after I added appropriate permission, it works.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. If you could detail a bit on how you solved it and post it as an answer to this question, that'd be very helpful for me and others having the same issue.

Comment: The problem I had is related to permission of the node role. In my organisation, we have attached permission boundary to every roles. I have assigned these four policies to the node role, AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy, AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy, AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly, CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy. I found some actions are excluded from the permission boundary. After updating the permission boundary, the unhealthy node issue is gone.

Answer (score 3):

Add pod network add-on

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/2140ac876ef134e0ed5af15c65e414cf26827915/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```